# Add and remove entries from a JavaScript array based on values

Tags: javascript

I have a Project Management app buildt with JavaScript on the front end and PHP/MySQL on the back end.

I want to have an array holding all the Task ID's that a user is subscribed to notifications on.

When I show a Task record I want to set the status of the subscribe button based on if the user is subscribed already or not.

I also want the ability to add and remove task entrioes from the users array of subscriptions.

I am thinking something like this below would be a good start...

```
var userTaskSubscriptions = [{
  task_id: 1,
  subscribed: 'yes'
},
{
  task_id: 2,
  subscribed: 'yes'
},
{
  task_id: 3,
  subscribed: 'yes'
}]
```

In this example above I need some JavaScript code to allow me to check if user has an entry above for Task ID #2 and min this case they would have one.

I also need code to add and remove entries from it.

Any help here?

Comment: The question is not clear. Please, can you provide an example with input and desired output?

Comment: Are you using an ES6 environment? ie, is `Map`, `Array.prototype.find`, etc, available?

Answer (score 2):

You can just loop trough it (by array size) and delete the index where the match is found.

```
function deleteTask(taskId) {
    for(var i = 0; i < userTaskSubscriptions.length; i++) {
        if(userTaskSubscriptions[i] == taskId) {
            userTaskSubscriptions.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please try with this code:  Check whether task_id is already
>   subscribed or not, if it is 'yes', will delete from list and return
>   subscribed value 'yes'.  It will add new user to the list with two
>   filled 'task_id' and subscribed value 'yes', which is default.

```
 var userTaskSubscriptions = [{
      task_id: 1,
      subscribed: 'yes'
    },
    {
      task_id: 2,
      subscribed: 'yes'
    },
    {
      task_id: 3,
      subscribed: 'yes'
    }];
    var subscribe=function(taskId){
     var _self=this;
      _self.taskId=taskId;
     var subscritpiton;
     $.each(userTaskSubscriptions,function(index,value){
       console.log(userTaskSubscriptions);
          if(taskId == value.task_id){

             userTaskSubscriptions.splice(index, 1);
             subscritpiton=value.subscribed;
             return false;
           }
          else{

             userTaskSubscriptions.push({task_id: _self.taskId,subscribed: 'yes'})
              return false;
          }
        })
    console.log(userTaskSubscriptions);
    return subscritpiton;
    };

subscribe(1); //call subscribe method here
```